# Why is yarn not found as a package manager in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, yarnpkg

I have yarn installed on Ubuntu 18.04

```
yarn --version

0.32
```

But in `PhpStorm -> Settings -> Languages and Frameworks -> Node.js and NPM` it says yarn is not found.

[image: PhpStorm]

Comment: Please point it to executable file (full path) -- just `yarn` might not be enough as IDE may not be able to find it in the `PATH` that it can see.

Comment: @LazyOne when I run `which yarn` I get `/usr/bin/yarn`, so when I enter that it says Error: Invalid npm/yarn package: no such directory

Comment: Sorry, no better ideas from me. I could not find any [posts on WebStorm Forums](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200367229-WebStorm) that may have the same issue. What's your IDE version BTW -- maybe it worth updating to the latest stable or even try EAP build if it's not the latest 2018.1.x

Comment: I have the same version as on the current download page.

Comment: Another idea -- what about permissions then? You seem to be on Linux. What if you launch IDE from terminal and not via icon? Will it make any difference?

Comment: Tried that now and there is no change "Cannot resolve 'yarn' package manager"

Comment: Last idea from me: you have `yarn --version` = **0.32**. The https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/ website shows "Stable: **v1.7.0**". Try upgrading yarn.

Comment: yes, upgrading solved it (I had to remove cmdtest first then install yarn again), I will accept your answer if you post it

Comment: please specify a full path to yarn package ( not a binary): `<npm prefix>/lib/node_modules/yarn`, like `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to upgrade yarn

```
sudo apt remove cmdtest && sudo apt remove yarn && sudo apt install yarn
```